# Java - Transfer JFrame to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, media-player

I have video player class that extends JFrame, because I need to run this frame in stage (Jafafx by using SwingNode), I need to transfer this class to JPanel. 
This is possible? 
I tried to change, but created problems in EventHangler class, and "visualComponent" not show in the panel, only controlsComponent.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.media.*;

public class MediaPlayerDemo extends JFrame {
  private Player player;
  private File file;

  public MediaPlayerDemo()
  {
     super( "Demonstrating the Java Media Player" );

     JButton openFile = new JButton( "Open file to play" );
     openFile.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
           {
              openFile();
              createPlayer();
           }
        }
     );
     getContentPane().add( openFile, BorderLayout.NORTH );

     setSize( 300, 300 );
     show();
  }

  private void openFile()
  {      
     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

     fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(
        JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );
     int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( this );

     // user clicked Cancel button on dialog
     if ( result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION )
        file = null;
     else
        file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  }

  private void createPlayer()
  {
     if ( file == null )
        return;

     removePreviousPlayer();

     try {
        // create a new player and add listener
        player = Manager.createPlayer( file.toURL() );
        player.addControllerListener( new EventHandler() );
        player.start();  // start player
     }
     catch ( Exception e ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,
           "Invalid file or location", "Error loading file",
           JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
     }
  }

  private void removePreviousPlayer()
  {
     if ( player == null )
        return;

     player.close();

     Component visual = player.getVisualComponent();
     Component control = player.getControlPanelComponent();

     Container c = getContentPane();

     if ( visual != null ) 
        c.remove( visual );

     if ( control != null ) 
        c.remove( control );
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     MediaPlayerDemo app = new MediaPlayerDemo();

     app.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
           {
              System.exit(0);
           }
        }
     );
  }

  // inner class to handler events from media player
  private class EventHandler implements ControllerListener {
     public void controllerUpdate( ControllerEvent e ) {
        if ( e instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent ) {
           Container c = getContentPane();

           // load Visual and Control components if they exist
           Component visualComponent =
              player.getVisualComponent();

           if ( visualComponent != null )
              c.add( visualComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER );

           Component controlsComponent =
              player.getControlPanelComponent();

           if ( controlsComponent != null )
              c.add( controlsComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

           c.doLayout();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn the JFrame into a JPanel do the following:

1. Change "*public class MediaPlayerDemo extends JFrame*" to "*public class MediaPlayerDemo extends JPanel*"
2. Remove *show()*, *setSize(..)* and *app.addWindowListener(..)*
3. Replace "*getContentPane()*" with "*this*"

> **EDIT:** You should also replace *super( "Demonstrating the Java Media Player" )*; with *super( new BorderLayout() );* **–  Eric Leibenguth**

Also *show()* in JFrame is deprecated, meaning that you shouldn't use it. Use *setVisible(true);*

You can also replace your window closing event with *frame.[setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);*

Good luck with your video player!

Comment: What are the errors? (I am not familiar with the library that you are using)

Comment: You should also replace `super( "Demonstrating the Java Media Player" );` with `super( new BorderLayout() );`